# How to get the next correct position based off of the first object's Vector3 in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vector

This feels like a super noob question but, basically I am working on a project that the user basically puts down an object and I want to instantiate another object to the right or left of the object but along either the correct x or z depending on the direction the user is facing.

For example, if the user places an object at (0,0,1) and the user is at (0,0,0) I would want the next object at the same z-plane but with a different x. However, I don't know where the user is going to place the object and it could be placed at (1,0,0) in which case I would want to manipulate the z variable instead of the x.

The real question is how would I know which variable I would need to change, x or/and z?

I can get the four cardinal directions but how would I get all of the values along the line? Or is there a better way of doing this?

```
public Vector3 GetNextPos(Vector3 position)
{
    if (Camera.main.transform.rotation.y == 0)
    {
        return position += new Vector3(-0.1f, 0, 0);
    }

    if (Camera.main.transform.rotation.y == 90)
    {
        return position += new Vector3(0, 0, 0.1f);
    }

    if (Camera.main.transform.rotation.y == 180)
    {
        return position += new Vector3(0.1f, 0, 0);
    }

    if (Camera.main.transform.rotation.y == -90)
    {
        return position += new Vector3(0, 0, -0.1f);
    }
}
```

[image: What I want to do]

Comment: Can they only place on that line as shown, or is it anywhere on the edge of a circle around the user?

Comment: They can place the object wherever the user is looking typically the object is 1m in front of the user

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what the code would look like in unity but the math is fairly simple: `if( MagnitudeSqr( (Abs(transofrm.forward) + Abs(position)) - Abs(playerPos) ) > MagnitudeSqr( (Abs(transofrm.right) + Abs(position)) - Abs(playerPos) ) ) position +=  transform.forward else position += transform.right`. Basically, if the player is closer to the objects forward/-forward then it follows you'd want to place an object along transform.right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `forward` and `right` vectors from the `transform` component of your camera:

```
Vector3 position = Camera.main.transform.position;
Vector3 forward  = Camera.main.transform.forward;
Vector3 left     = -Camera.main.transform.right;

//first object is one unit in front of the camera
Vector3 firstObjectPosition = position + forward;

//second object is one unit left of the first object
Vector3 secondObjectPosition = firstObjectPosition + left;
```

Comment: I was overthinking this way too much haha that works